# vlookup - Is it possible to use vlookup to pull specific info like this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

[image: Data Sample]

I am trying to pull the following from each group of Numbers -

```
CHG000509443 05-16-2016 22:48:41 for the Requested
CHG000509443 05-17-2016 13:14:35 for the Approved
```

Note 1 - It is always the first Requested in each group - See CHG000509448

Note 2 - It is always the 0 duration Approved in each group - See CHG000510593

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you are pulling the data from? I assume your image is what you are trying to reproduce?

Comment: I pull the data from a different source and then play with it.

Comment: Sounds like a job for pivot table

Comment: Also look into a =MATCH and =INDEX function used together. I don't think VBA is needed,

Comment: @EricF I *know* VBA isn't needed, but I was thinking more along the lines of `frequency` or `sumproduct` rather than `index(match)`

Comment: @Raystafarian That would work too. I try to avoid VBA unless absolutely needed or formulas are going to slow the workbook down

Comment: @Ducatiduke, did you get this solved?  The comments on the answer looked promising and then you described a glitch.  If the answer worked, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That helps other users with a similar problem by identifying proven solutions.  It also awards a little rep to you both for the effort.  The answer goes above and beyond the intended scope of an answer, so if it solved your problem, consider upvoting it also.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code in VBA will do it:

```
Public Sub ReqandAppr()
    '****************
    ' variables
    SourceSheet = "Sheet1" 'name of source sheet
    DestSheet = "Sheet2"   ' name of destination sheet
    columntocheck = 5  'Column to check "Requested" or "Approved"
    firstrow = 2 'first row in source sheet
    destrow = 1  'first row in destination sheet
    'end of variables
    '*******************
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wksSource, wksDest As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkSource = wkb.Sheets(SourceSheet)
    Set wkDest = wkb.Sheets(DestSheet)
    wkDest.Rows.Clear
    totalrows = wkSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = firstrow To totalrows
        If wkSource.Cells(i, 1) <> wkSource.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            requestedfound = False
            approvedfound = False
        End If
        Select Case wkSource.Cells(i, columntocheck)
            Case "Requested"
                If requestedfound = False Then
                    wkSource.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wkDest.range("A" & destrow)
                    requestedfound = True
                    destrow = destrow + 1
                End If
            Case "Approved"
                If approvedfound = False And wkSource.Cells(i, columntocheck - 1) = 0 Then
                    wkSource.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wkDest.range("A" & destrow)
                    approvedfound = True
                    destrow = destrow + 1
                End If
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Open VBA/MAcros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste the code on the right side.

Check the value of the variables and execute it.

Comment: Wow!  I will give it a try!  If it works, I am going to somehow find you and take care of you!!!!

Comment: @Ducatiduke that's an awkward way of saying you will upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry!  I am just very happy!

Comment: Hi! I finally got to this but i am pulling a run-time error "9" Subscript out of range when i run this as described above. It is pointing to the line "Set wkSource = wkb.Sheets(SourceSheet) 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=961ACBB557F739BB!353377&authkey=!APP2NhLp0yNiE7g&ithint=folder%2cpng
I had to post the screen shots and the ss in a onedrive... For some reason, i cannot sign into imgur.

Comment: @Ducatiduke. You renamed `Sheet1` to `Page 1` but didn't change it in the *variables* area of the code. Besides that you don't have a second sheet (in variables it's called `Sheet2`). The code uses it to put the final results.